# What is kind:test in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

One of my project which is using kubernetes to manage the containers has something called **test**. Where developer has defined connectivity.

I tried to search it over the internet but found nothing which can clear this.

Can somebody help me to understand this kind and connectivity in test.yml?

```
kind: test
spec:
   connectivity:
      to:
      from
```

Comment: It doesn't appear standard. It's probably for a custom operator. `kubectl get crd` to see it's spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kind: Test` is a CustomResource (CR).
CRs can be used in a cluster after [applying a CustomResourceDefinition (CRD) that describes all the fields](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#create-a-customresourcedefinition).

By doing so you extend Kubernetes with new objects that can be used. This is useful if you want to [write your own operator or controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/operator/).
Without an operator/controller the CR is **not doing anything**. It will just hold some information that you can lookup (similar to a ConfigMap) but it will not do anything.

Here is an explanation on how Kubernetes works for in-built objects such as a Deployment:

1. You use `kubectl apply -f some-deployment.yaml`
2. Your call will be sent to the kube-apiserver
3. The kube-apiserver will save the information (`name` of the Deployment, `replicas`, `image` to use, ...) in etcd
4. The kube-controller-manager continuously communicates to the kube-apiserver and asks him to show him all information there is regarding Deployments.
5. The kube-apiserver retrieves the information from etcd and sends it back to the kube-controller-manager
6. The kube-controller-manager sees that there is a new Deployment (the one you applied) and will now proceed on creating the Pods (and before that the ReplicaSet).

As you can see the one that *actually* creates the Pods is the kube-controller-manager.

In case the kube-controller-manager does not support all the features you expect from Kubernetes, you are able to create your own controller which is called an operator by [using the operator SDK](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk). Your operator can then watch all objects that you will create as a CustomResource (such as `Test`).

To check all the CRDs you applied on your cluster execute:

```sh
$ kubectl get crd
```

To get a list of *all* objects that you can apply to Kubernetes execute the following:

```sh
$ kubectl api-resources
```

Comment: You have clear all the doubts in just one answer. Thank you for that. Request you to change the kind example in your answer. I have changed it in my question due to some compliances.

Comment: Post updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**It's what we call creating `CustomResourceDefinition` (CRD) in kubernetes world**.

> Read the docs : [Using Custom Resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/_print/) for clarity.